# C - Trying to send() data but there is bug

Tags: c, send

I am trying to send data line by line from file using `GET` request (newline removed). Problem is when I check my apache access log, request with line where are three words together separated by space is not sent even if I url encode it (2x encoding also).

Example of text file:

```
asd

asd asd

asd asd asd <- not sent
```

Code:

```
asprintf(&httpget, 
        "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n"
        "User-Agent: \r\n"
        "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,;q=0.5\r\n"
        "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n"
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n"
        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n"
        "Cache-Control: max-age=\r\n"
        "\r\n", line_buffer);

send(socket_handle, httpget, strlen(httpget), 0);
```

Request should be valid since I tried to replicate request using other scripts.

So I found out something...

When you send `a a` it will do the request but after that another line is not sent. But I still don't think thats problem of webserver or invalid header, cause for example in BurpSuite I can send these url unencoded data without any problem and log looks like

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2014:13:37:04 +0100] "GET /test test test HTTP/1.1" 200 54
```

Complete code:

```
  socket_handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ;
  socket_detials.sin_family = AF_INET ;
  socket_detials.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
  socket_detials.sin_port = htons(80);
  input_buffer = malloc(20000);
  line_number = 0;
  while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), infile)) {
    ++line_number;
    strtok(line_buffer, "\n");
    printf("\n\n%s\n\n", line_buffer);
    asprintf(&httpget, 
      "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
      "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n"
      "User-Agent: \r\n"
      "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,;q=0.5\r\n"
      "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n"
      "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n"
      "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n"
      "Cache-Control: max-age=\r\n"
      "\r\n", line_buffer);
    bzero(&(socket_detials.sin_zero), 8);
    connect(socket_handle,(struct sockaddr*)&socket_detials, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if(send(socket_handle, httpget, strlen(httpget), 0) < 0) {
  printf("\n\n\n ERROR send() \n\n\n");
    }
    int recieved = recv(socket_handle, input_buffer, 20000, 0);
if(recieved != 0) {
      printf ("\rRecieved %d bytes | Requests made: %d        ", recieved, req++);
      printf("\n%s\n", httpget);
  printf("%s%s\n%s\n", gray, input_buffer, normal);
} else {
  printf ("\rRecieved %d bytes | Requests made: %d        ", recieved, req++);
  printf("\n%sRequest not sent.%s \n\nResponse:\n\n", red, normal);
  printf("\n%s\n", httpget);
  printf("%s%s\n%s\n", gray, input_buffer, normal);
    }
  }
```

Why after probably invalid request is socket closing?

Comment: Do you by any chance use non-blocking socket to send out the data?

Comment: What exactly do you think? :)

Comment: Does you your real code check what `send()` returns?

Comment: Only with if(send(socket_handle, httpget, strlen(httpget), 0) < 0)

Comment: So again, what kind of socket do you use: blocking or non-blocking. You might like to show the code you use to create it, and in case you do use `setsockopt()` all calls to the latter as well.

Comment: Code is already there :)

Answer (score 1):

You should lookup URL encoding in the HTTP RFC. Spaces need to be encoded as '%20' but there are lots of other characters that also require encoding. This looks to be extremely inefficient compared to POSTing the text file to the server.

Comment: I know it should be url encoded, but why it is working somehow using other program? I am trying to fuzz webserver. I don't want to send any file to server :)